# SalesForce - country auto complete?

Tags: salesforce

When my users create accounts in SalesForce, they usually mis-type the name of the country.

Is there some way to autocomplete them with the account standard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not auto-complete, but dropdown is available natively.[Implementing Country Picklist](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&type=0)